# simple express API errors

Tags: javascript, express

I keep receiving the following error when running my express API below shows the error i get in terminal, and have broken the code out in 3 blocks which will be three seperate sheets. if you could look at it and let me know. I also added that i went in and re isntalled/ recoded the work a couple of times.

```
*internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
throw err;
^
  Error: Cannot find module '/Users/eddie/Desktop/AllProjects/node- 
rest- 
  shop/node_modules/server.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:576:3)
```

i have reinstalled npm install express --save , i rewrote my code several times  below shows the code

server.js code

```
const http = require('http');
const app = require('./app')

const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const server = http.createServer(app);


server.listen(port)
```

app.js code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()


const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products')
//middleware 
app.use('/products', productRoutes)

module.exports = app
```

products.js code

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Handling get request to /products'
  })
})

router.post('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    message: 'Handling post request to  /products'
  })
})


module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What command are you using to run your application? `node server.js`?

Comment: Since server.js is what bootstraps your application, I'm assuming your startup script is the problem. Whenever you start a node application, typically you write `node <filename.js>` and I'm assuming the path which you're passing to the `node` cli is an invalid path.

Comment: I used node server.js and i still get the error

Comment: Can you post the error please.